# Is there a way to fix the sms notification in Galaxy S2, ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms, notifications

The SMS notification behavior is inconsistent on the Samsung Galaxy S2 after upgrading to 4.0.3 ICS.  When receiving a text message, the phone does not make a sound or vibrate, regardless of the notification settings, and regardless of the sms app used (including the default).  The screen will turn on.  This problem will go away after rebooting, but then it will return after time. This is a problem that has been discussed in [several](http://forums.att.com/t5/Android-Discussion-and-Support/updated-to-ics-on-Galaxy-S2-and-now-no-notification-sounds/td-p/3243669) [forums](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-t/573384-ics-notifications-sounds-issue.html).

Is there a fix for this?  I'm open to rooting my phone.  I have already done a factory reset since upgrading from Gingerbread to ICS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see this issue on a custom ROM - is it an issue with the stock Samsung ROM?

I would suggest you find out - and if you *really* want to get rid of it, install a custom ROM onto your phone after rooting - I find Sapir's CM10 ROM to work well, and I do not see this issue.

Please check http://forum.xda-developers.com for more info on rooting and installing custom ROM's to your device.

Comment: Yes, this is an issue with the stock ICS ROM.  It was actually because of this issue that I decided to install a custom ROM.